# How to make a variable be equal to a letter in C++?

Tags: c++, char

I try to make a simple program in C++, as I am a beginner. The program is supposed to tell you the "swag value", so if you write anything in the console except "Nicu", which is the name of one of my friends, the program will say "Swag level over 9000". If you write "Nicu", though it will say "Sorry, couldn't find swag in the database". My question is how do I make the program give me that answer when I write "Nicu" ? Here's how I've thought the program :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char b,a;
    a='Nicu';
    cout<<"Insert your name: ";
    cin>>b;
    if (b==a){
    cout<<"Sorry ! Couldn't find swag in database... "<<endl;
}
    else if (b!=a){
    cout<<"Swag level over 9000 "<<endl;
}

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

And this is the error it gives me : [Error]Id returned 1 exit status, and it highlights the `a='Nicu'` part of the code.
Even though I used `char` in this code, I still don't know what it does, but at least I am sure that `int` can't be used with letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is used for storing a *single character*.

You can use `std::string` to store a string.

Rewriting,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string a = "Nicu";
  string b;
  cout<<"Insert your name: ";
  cin>>b;
  if (b==a){
    cout<<"Sorry ! Couldn't find swag in database... "<<endl;
  }
  else if (b!=a){
    cout<<"Swag level over 9000 "<<endl;
  }
  system ("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string b, a;
a = "Nicu";
cout<<"Insert your name: ";
cin>>b;
if (b==a){
cout<<"Sorry ! Couldn't find swag in database... "<<endl;
}
else if (b!=a){
cout<<"Swag level over 9000 "<<endl;
}

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use string instead of char ??
for compare a string you should use "strcomp"

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
int main()
{
    string other;
    string that;
    if(strcmp(other, "hi")) // comparing the characters in this string with the text possibility "hi."
    {
    // do whatever you want if they are equal.
    }
    //Or.
    if(strcmp(other, that)) // comparing both strings rather than a string with a possibly extracted text to compare it with alongside another string comparing both strings at once.
    {
    // do whatever you want if they are equal.
    }
}
```

Comment: It is kind of hard for me to understand what you said there. I am not saying your explanation is wrong, but maybe it will be useful for me after 1-2 months or so. Thank you, anyway :D